# Simplify dereferencing void pointer

Tags: c++

This WINAPI thread callback:

```
DWORD WINAPI dont_thread_on_me(LPVOID context) {
    int value = *((int *)context);
    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

in particular the line:

```
    int value = *((int *)context);
```

works. But `*((int *)context)` is all sorts of nasty. Is there a better way to write that?

Comment: You're not dereferencing a `void*` after casting to `int*`. Also, you cannot dereference a `void*` at all.

Comment: "ERROR_SUCCESS" got to love that..

Comment: @NeilKirk The function returns an error code. The code 0 is reserved for `no error` a.k.a. SUCCESS.

Comment: @harper It was a joke..

Comment: @MikeSeymour Required signature for a LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @MikeSeymour Probably because he has no choice due to the API?

Comment: @NeilKirk: Oh yes, I didn't spot the context in the first line. I guess nastiness is unavoidable, if you're forced to use a nasty API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int value = *reinterpret_cast<int *>(context);
```

You can't really get around the fact there is a cast if that is required.

Comment: Although effectively the same, I appreciate the reminder to use *actual* casts. +1 Thanks.

Comment: C-style cast is still an actual cast.

Comment: Wouldn't it be sufficient to use static_cast in this case?

Comment: @KevinCadieux If `LPVOID` may ever change from void, then it would break. I've never done WINAPI so I don't know.

Comment: @NeilKirk is there ever a situation where a C-cast does something that a C++ cannot do?

Comment: @sircodesalot As far as I know, a C-cast attempts a static_cast and if that is not possible it then attempts a reinterpret_cast.

Comment: C cast might be called 'convoluted_cast<>' in C++ nomenclature. ' is there ever a situation where a C-cast does something that a C++ cannot do?' - No, and that's the problem. One Cast to Cast them All, and the rules which of the numerous casts will be picked depending on context (and what the end result will be) would probably need a lengthy cheat-sheet and is a special point of generating bugs that are really hard to trace - the object *will* get cast into *something* for sure, and in about 95% cases, just into what you wanted it cast into. Now the remaining 5%...

Answer (score 3):

you can use `reinterpret_cast`:

```
int value = *reinterpret_cast<int *>(context);
```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler must know how to treat the `context`. So you have to tell the compiler with a cast that it points to an `int`. You can hide this with a macro like

```
#define read_as_int(p) *(reinterpret_cast<int*>(p))

int value = read_as_int(context);
```

but this doesn't improve neither readability nor effort to type the code. C++ purists might prefer an inline function:

```
int inline read_as_function(void*p) 
{ 
    return *(reinterpret_cast<int*>(p));
}
```

Comment: Macros are against my religion. :)

Comment: @sircodesalot I can't help with religious questions as these are too personal.

Comment: Why use a compiler-specific keyword and not simple `inline`?

Answer (score 1):

Although the question is tagged C++, it is perfectly valid as a C question as well (and I never can tell if people tag questions accurately), so ...

In C, it is often written:

```
foo( void *v ) {
  int *ip = v;
  int x = *ip;
```

Whether this is elegant or a gaping hole in the type system is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: `Whether this is elegant or a gaping hole in the type system is a matter of personal preference.` +1 -- That's both awesome and terrible at the same time!

Comment: Since it is a C++ question it allows answers with `reinterpret_cast`.